# Cordova resume event not firing on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have developed an App with Cordova.
On resume event I make an Ajax call. It worked perfectly on Android and iOS but yesterday I recompiled the app, and now resume event doesn't fire on iOS. I didn't change anything. The plugins are the same. The only thing that is changed is iOS version on my test device (iOS 10.3.2). On Android it is still working.
I use Cordova cli 6.5.0 and Cordova ios 4.3.1
Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem. I use Framework7 for my cordova app. F7 version 1.6.2 and later makes onresume event not to work on ios devices.